# Wrap string at a certain length and replace wrappings with '\n'

Tags: r, string, apply, word-wrap

I have a string that looks like:

```
str <- c("some text", "another one, that is a bit longer", "yet another one")
```

Now I want to wrap that string to a certain width and afterwards replace all those wrappings with '\n'.

The following code does what I want (here: wrapping at maximum width 10):

```
str <- sapply(str, function(x) {paste0(strwrap(x, width = 10), collapse = "\n")})
names(str) <- NULL
str
```

The expected output is:

```
# [1] "some text"                            "another\none, that\nis a bit\nlonger"
# [3] "yet\nanother\none"
```

However this code seems fairly complicated to me (given the simplicity of the question). Are there more concise options to achieve what I want?

---

*Some more context about the why:
My string contains labels of an igraph object. I want to wrap those labels at certain lengths. But of course the number of labels must be constant throughout the processing..*

Comment: Just apply `strwrap` on the entire vector `str_wrap(str, width = 10)`

Comment: @akrun do you mean "apply `stringr::str_wrap` on the vector"?

Comment: @Spacedman  Yes, I get the expected output with that

Comment: Your code is sufficient, I think, and in my opinion not overly-complicated. The use of `string::str_wrap` just does effectively the same thing internally (using `vapply` instead, with some sanity). (You could lose the braces `{` and `}`, if you're going for code-golf.) If this is your only use of the `stringr` package, then one could argue that adding a dependency just for this use is adding an unnecessary "complexity" (actually: "dependency") to your code.